# Перестал загружаться kali linux

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux

Случайно удалила файл `vmlinuz-4.19.0-kali5-amd64` и сразу этого не заметила при пeрезагрузке выбивает ошибку `/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-kali5-amd64 файл не найден`. 
Возможно где то скачать отдельно этот файл или все таки нужно переустанавливать ОС ?

Comment: LiveCD (или USB) в помощь, потом `chroot` на раздел и установка из пакета ядра заново. Прокачаете скиллы по восстановлению ОС, хотя это и не hard вариант.

Comment: Ну просто ацки неимоверный куул хацкер:)

Comment: @Sergey, ваш комплимент греет мне душу, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

**предуведомление**: все описанные ниже манипуляции можно произвести, загрузившись с live-образа любого дистрибутива *gnu/linux*, и примонтировав тот раздел на вашем блочном устройстве, где содержится каталог `boot`, из которого и был удалён файл. процедуры поиска нужного раздела и его монтирования я опускаю в целях сокращения размера ответа.

---

удалили вы саму программу *linux*.

очевидно, что «искать» её следует в репозитории вашего дистрибутива: https://http.kali.org/kali

сами пакеты находятся в каталоге `pool`, интересующий нас пакет располагается, естественно, в секции `main` (ну а в какую ещё секцию может быть помещена программа *linux*? учитывая, что некоторые шутники абсолютно серьёзно вообще называют её «операционной системой»). далее заглядываем в каталог `l` (с этой буквы начинается слово `linux`, и наконец находим нужный каталог: https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/

там много чего находится, нас интересуют пакеты, содержащие в имени, во-первых, слово `image`, во-вторых, упомянутую вами версию: `4.19.0-kali5-amd64`, и в-третьих, **не** содержат в имени слово `dbg` (это пакеты с отладочной информацией). к счастью, таковых получается всего два:

```
$ w3m -dump https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/ | grep image | grep 4.19.0-kali5-amd64 | grep -v dbg
[ ]         kernel-image-4.19.0-kali5-amd64-di_4.19.37-6kali1_amd64.udeb            2019-07-22 5.4M  
[ ]         linux-image-4.19.0-kali5-amd64_4.19.37-6kali1_amd64.deb                 2019-07-22  45M
```

основное отличие этих двух пакетов в том, что первый из них — используемый лишь [инсталлятором «udeb»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)#udeb), он не содержит, например, собранных модулей. второе, несущественное отличие (это я забегаю чуть вперёд) — файл с программой *linux* в первом из пакетов носит короткое имя `vmlinuz`, а во втором — длинное `vmlinuz-4.19.0-kali5-amd64` (опять забегая вперёд — содержимое этих файлов абсолютно идентично).

скачаем тот, что поменьше (для второго пакета процедура абсолютно идентична):

```
$ wget https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/kernel-image-4.19.0-kali5-amd64-di_4.19.37-6kali1_amd64.udeb
```

и начнём извлекать то, что нам требуется. сначала посмотрим содержимое:

```
$ ar vt kernel-image-4.19.0-kali5-amd64-di_4.19.37-6kali1_amd64.udeb 
rw-r--r-- 0/0      4 Jul 22 12:27 2019 debian-binary
rw-r--r-- 0/0    504 Jul 22 12:27 2019 control.tar.xz
rw-r--r-- 0/0 5628080 Jul 22 12:27 2019 data.tar.xz
```

ага, очевидно, что извлекать надо `data.tar.xz` — только этот файл имеет достаточно большой размер (5628080 байт):

```
$ ar x kernel-image-4.19.0-kali5-amd64-di_4.19.37-6kali1_amd64.udeb data.tar.xz
```

фильтруем его содержимое на предмет строки `vmlinuz`:

```
$ tar -tf data.tar.xz | grep vmlinuz
./boot/vmlinuz
```

нашлась такая буква в этом слове! извлекаем и перемещаем файл туда, куда требуется, и под тем именем, что нам требуется:

```
$ tar -xf data.tar.xz ./boot/vmlinuz
$ sudo mv ./boot/vmlinuz /куда/примонтирован/раздел/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-kali5-amd64
```

на этом всё! спасибо, что смогли дочитать до этого места.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас сохранился установочный CD-диск/флэшка - загрузитесь с него и скопируйте этот файл руками. Он должен быть на диске!

Если у Вас нет диска/флэшки - проще всего скачать с сайта дистрибутива.